# ActiveMQ Artemis Version Over MBean

Tags: activemq-artemis, jolokia

I have checked the [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/) but couldn't find one. Is there a way to get the Artemis version over MBean which I can invoke through Jolokia interface?

Comment: The `ActiveMQServerControl` MBean has a `version` property as noted in [the JavaDoc](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.html#getVersion--). A sample Jolokia URL is available via the web console for any JMX attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found on the management interface:

```
http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=%22<broker_name>%22/Version
```